# Why $\text{Explained Variance} = Cov(y, \hat{y})$?

Tags: multiple-regression, covariance

**Context:**

We all know:
$$
\text{Total Variance}=\text{Unexplained Variance} + \text{Explained Variance}
$$
where,
$$
\text{Explained Variance} = \text{SSReg} = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-\bar y)^2     
$$

Now, I was doing some random experiments in R. During that, I (empirically) found this this relationship to hold as well:
$$
\text{Explained Variance} = Cov(y, \hat{y})
$$
(where n = number of observations)

---

**Experiment:**

Eg. My Sample R run:

```
attach(mtcars)

n      <- nrow(mtcars)

fit    <- lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec + hp + drat, data=mtcars)

y_hat  <- predict(fit, data.frame(wt, qsec, hp, drat))

y_mean <- mean(mpg)

ans_1  <-  sum( (y_hat - y_mean)^2 ) / (n-1)
print(ans_1)

ans_2  <- cov(mpg, y_hat)
print(ans_2)

if (ans_1 == ans_2){
    print('Equal')
} else {
    print('Unequal')
}
```

---

**Doubt:**

Despite being equal empirically (in R runs), I am unable to prove  mathematically that why the above two equations are equivalent, i.e. why does
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-\bar y)^2 = Cov(y, \hat{y})
$$

Can someone please prove it mathematically?

Comment: Your final expression is missing division by $n-1$.  This does not really affect your point which is that $\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-\bar y)^2$ is the sample variance of $\hat y$ - try `var(y_hat)` - and in ordinary linear least-squares regression this is always equal to the covariance.

Comment: Thanks Henry, corrected the typo.

Comment: I am able to see $\hat{\bar y}=\bar{y}$, so it will indeed be sample variance of $\hat{y}$

Comment: But I unable to see how variance equals covariance, i.e. $var(\hat{y}) = cov(y, \hat{y})$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathrm{cov}[y,\hat y]=\mathrm{cov}[y-\hat y+\hat y,\hat y]=\mathrm{cov}[\hat y,\hat y]+\mathrm{cov}[y-\hat y,\hat y]$$
Now $\mathrm{cov}[\hat y,\hat y]=\mathrm{var}[\hat y]$ by definition, and for OLS $y-\hat y$ is uncorrelated with $\hat y$, so $\mathrm{cov}[y-\hat y,\hat y]=0$

Comment: Thank a lot :) Thomas!

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Lumley has already [answered](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/590802/362671). Nevertheless, for the sake of completeness and that OP might find it helpful, I'm leaving behind a relevant relationship.

---

From the following identity:

$$(y_i-\hat y_i) = (y_i-\bar y) -(\hat y_i -\bar y),\tag 1$$

one can deduce easily

$$\sum ( y_i -\bar y)^2 = \sum(\hat y_i -\bar y)^2 + \sum (y_i - \hat y_i) ^2,\tag 2$$ with the cross product term being $0.$

Now, $\text{SSR} = \sum(\hat y_i -\bar y)^2.$ Also \begin{align}\sum(\hat y_i -\bar y)^2 &=b_1^2S_{XX}\\ &= \frac{S_{XY}^2}{S_{XX}} .\tag 3\end{align}

Also, $r^2_{XY}= R^2.$

Again, $$\begin{align}r_{Y\hat Y}&=\frac{\sum \left(\hat y_i - \bar{\hat y_i}\right)(y_i-\bar y) }{\left\{\sum \left(\hat y_i -\hat{\bar y_i}\right)^2\right\}^{1/2}\left\{\sum ( y_i -\bar y) ^2\right\}^{1/2}}\\ &= \frac{{b_1}\sum \left(x_i - \bar{x}\right)(y_i-\bar y) }{\left\{\sum b_1^2\left(x_i -\bar x\right)^2\right\}^{1/2}\left\{\sum ( y_i -\bar y) ^2\right\}^{1/2}}\\ &= r_{XY}.\tag 4\end{align}$$

Therefore

$$ r^2_{XY} = R^2= r^2_{Y\hat Y}.\tag 5$$

In fact, using the latter part of the relation in $(5), $ OP can conclude what is desired.

---

### Reference:

$[\rm I]$ Applied Regression Analysis, *Norman R. Draper, Harry Smith*, John Wiley & Sons, $1998, $ exercises for chapters $1-3, $ problem $\mathbf{ P.},$ p. $103.$